# Debugging UEFI with QEMU on Windows

Tags: windbg, qemu, uefi

I apologize for my English. I want to debug UEFI applications using WinDbg and UEFI (which will run OVMF). How I try to run:

1. Collect the image **OVMF** defining in the file .dsc macros **source_debug_enable** **debug_on_serial_port**
2. Copy the **OVMF.fd** file to directory with qemu
3. I Start qemu with `qemu-system-x86_64-bios OVMF.fd-serial pipe:Dbg`
4. I Start Windbg with command `com:pipe,baud=115200,port=\.\pipe\Dbg, resets=0`

And nothing happens. Qemu window starts but hangs and hangs for half an hour (did not wait longer). The debugger says that is waiting for reconnection.

What am I doing wrong?